# Pyside Installation "Failed to find the MSVC compiler version 10.0 on your system"

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, frameworks, pyside

I'm currently in the process of developing a gui for my python script and want to do that by using PySide.

Right now I just can't get it up and running. PIP alwyas exits with this error:

```
nmake not found. Trying to initialize the MSVC env... 
Searching MSVC compiler version 10.0 error: Failed to find the MSVC compiler version 10.0 on your system.
```

I have the following components installed: 
Python 3.4.4 (64Bit)
QT 5.6 / 5.7 
Pycharm Community Edition

Windows 7 64Bit

I can run PIP and Python from the terminal without having to cd into the python directory. So my PATH Variables are set correctly.

Does anybody have the same issues or maybe a solution?

Best 
Jo

Comment: do you have `visual c++` installed?

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, I don't. Is there any particular version I have to use?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: During installation I an error message popped up, saying that I already have a newer version of this file installed. Is it still okay?

Answer (score 5):

> PySide requires Python 2.6 or later and Qt 4.6 or better.
>
> Qt 5.x is currently not supported.

From: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide/1.2.4#installing-pyside-on-a-windows-system

So maybe using qt4.x(>=4.6) instead of qt5.x can fix your problem.

---

I think the reason is that pip on your system install PySide from source package so you need a c/c++ complier.

Maybe you can install PySide binary version directly following this:

```
pip install PySide --only-binary :all:
```

---

If it doesn't work, please try to download ".exe" file, and run it instead of using pip.

".exe" from: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/pyside/

Comment: I just uninstalled QT 5 and installed QT 4.8.4 from here 
https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.4/
but the error is the same.

Comment: run `pip install pyside` again,  if you saw  "Downloading PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz " instead of "PySide*.whl ", it means pip install pyside from source package.    And i added the solution to my post.

Comment: Thank you, I can now start it from the console but when I try to run it from Python, I get the error message, that there is no module named PySide :(

Comment: @Johannes `pip uninstall pyside` and then `pip install PySide --only-binary :all:` might work

Comment: I already did that without any success. Or is there a way to do it inside of Pycharm?

Comment: @Johannes..how are you importing it/running it from python and are you sure it's the same version?

Comment: pip install PySide --only-binary :all: helped me. Thanks